# matlab - ??? Error using ==> syms at 61 Not a valid variable name

Tags: matlab

I'm having some problems with my code. Here is it:

```
syms I1(t) I2(t)
eqn1 = diff(I1(t),t) == 12-2*I1(t)+diff(I2(t),t); 
eqn2 = diff(I2(t),t) == 1/3*(diff(I1(t),t)-4); 
eqns = [egn1; eqn2]
cond1=I1(0)==0;
cond2=I2(0)==0;
conds=[cond1; cond2];
[I1Sol(t), I2Sol(t)]=dsolve(eqns, conds)
```

When i solve, i get

> ??? Error using ==> syms at 61
> Not a valid variable name.

I don't know how to fix it. I'm new to Matlab so i hope to someone to help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: You made a spelling mistake in `eqns = [egn1; eqn2]` at least, there's `egn1` instead of `eqn1`.

Comment: oh thanks. I fixed it but it still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

try now, and make sure you add folder contain your script to matlab "add path"

```
clear
clc
syms I1(t) I2(t)
eqn1 = diff(I1(t),t) == 12-2*I1(t)+diff(I2(t),t);
eqn2 = diff(I2(t),t) == 1/3*(diff(I1(t),t)-4);
eqns = [eqn1; eqn2]
cond1=I1(0)==0;
cond2=I2(0)==0;
conds=[cond1; cond2];
[I1Sol(t), I2Sol(t)]=dsolve(eqns, conds)
```

I got this result

```
eqns =
 
diff(I1(t), t) == diff(I2(t), t) - 2*I1(t) + 12
        diff(I2(t), t) == diff(I1(t), t)/3 - 4/3
 
I1Sol(t) =

3*exp(-3*t)*((16*exp(3*t))/9 - 16/9)

 
I2Sol(t) =
 
exp(-3*t)*((16*exp(3*t))/9 - 16/9) - (4*t)/3
```